# Multi Fragment Heuristic for Traveling Salesman(C++)

Tags: c++, greedy, traveling-salesman

I'm trying to implement Multi Fragment Heuristic algorithm for TSP.

Algorithm is like that:

1. Sort the edges in increasing order of their weights.(Ties can be broken arbitrarily.) Initialize the set of tour edges to be constructed to the empty set.
2. Repeat this step n times,where n is the number of cities in the instance being solved: add the next edge on the sorted edge list to the set of tour edges, provided this addition does not create a vertex of degree 3 or a cycle of length less than n; otherwise, skip the edge.
3. Return the set of tour edges.

I'm stuck with checking if there is cycle.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <queue>
static int repeat[6];
struct element{
    int distance;
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct element array[25];

void quicksort(struct element x[78400],int first,int last){
    int pivot,j,i;
    struct element temp;
    if(first<last){
        pivot=first;
        i=first;
        j=last;

        while(i<j){
            while(x[i].distance<=x[pivot].distance&&i<last)
                i++;
            while(x[j].distance>x[pivot].distance)
                j--;
            if(i<j){
                temp=x[i];
                x[i]=x[j];
                x[j]=temp;
            }
        }

        temp=x[pivot];
        x[pivot]=x[j];
        x[j]=temp;
        quicksort(x,first,j-1);
        quicksort(x,j+1,last);

    }
}
bool isCycle(){



    return true;
}

bool canAdd(int a){
    repeat[array[a].x]++;
    repeat[array[a].y]++;
    if(repeat[array[a].x] > 2 || repeat[array[a].y] > 2){
        repeat[array[a].x]--;
        repeat[array[a].y]--;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {


    int i = 0;

    int graph[6][6] = {
        {INT_MAX,4,8,9,12},
        {4,INT_MAX,6,8,9},
        {8,6,INT_MAX,10,11},
        {9,8,10,INT_MAX,7},
        {12,9,11,7,INT_MAX}
    };

    int an = 0;
    for(int a = 0; a<5; a++){
        for(int b = a; b<5; b++){
            array[an].x = a;
            array[an].y = b;
            array[an].distance = graph[a][b];
            an++;
        }
    }

    quicksort(array, 0, an-1);


    static int sayilar[6];
    for(int ya = 0; ya<6; ya++){
        sayilar[ya] = 0;
    }

    std::queue<element> tour;
    int edges = 0;

    while(edges != 5){
        printf("%d %d %d\n", array[i].x, array[i].y, array[i].distance);
        if(canAdd(i)){
            tour.push(array[i]);
            printf("oldu\n");
            if(isCycle()){
                tour.pop();
            }
        }
        i++;
        edges = (int)tour.size();
        printf("%d\n", edges);
    }


    return  0;
}
```

Is there any way to check to if there is a cycle?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

To test a graph for a cycle, set two pointers to the first edge/vertex. Move one one step every iteration, the other two steps per iteration. Check the two pointers for equality after each increment. If we have equality, the second pointer has looped round and caught up, and there is a cycle.

Answer (score -1):

When constructing fragments, check at each iteration if the starting city of the updated fragment is the same as the last one.

You may need to change you implementation to make this verification easier.

Also, I invite you to read my paper "*An Empirical Study of the Multi-fragment Tour Construction Algorithm for the Travelling Salesman Problem*" appeared in the Proceedings of the 16th International Conference on Hybrid Intelligent Systems (HIS 2016) pp 278-287. DOI: 10.1007/978-3-319-52941-7_28.